# Can I get an adapter to use a Fuji X mount lens on my Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, lens-adapter, fujifilm

Can I get an adapter for my Canon 1300D to use a Fuji X mount lens on my canon?

The reason for the adapter is the Fuji lens has infinity focus and my Canon lens doesn’t. It’s takes me along long time to focus in the dark for night shots.

Well it’s more like shooting stars and the Milky Way. A fellow Instagramer was going to loan me a Fuji lens, but I see it’s not worth trying to find the adapter. When I looked it seemed like everything was for EF lens to Fuji mirrorless camera.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more on the comment about infinity focus? Do you mean "focusing at something at an infinite distance away" or do you mean "everything in focus"? Why do you say the Fujifilm lens has it and your Canon lens does not?

Answer (score 2):

Adapters to use mirrorless-system lenses on other camera bodies generally don't exist for the following reasons:

- Incompatible [flange focal distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance).  With a few exceptions, FFD of lens must be longer than the FFD of the body.
- Electronic control of lens aperture and focus.  Lens would be unusable with a "dumb" adapter.
- Insufficient benefit (quality, cost savings, etc) vs using native lenses.

See [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000)

---

EF lenses have electronically controlled aperture and focus, so why are there so many adapters to use them on mirrorless bodies?

- EF lenses are very common because they have been manufactured for decades.  There is a large potential market.
- Many EF lenses can still be focused manually.  There is also a hack to control the aperture with a Canon body.
- The EF mount may be used as an intermediary to other mounts, such as OM, PK, M42, Adaptall, C/Y, Nikon F, etc.  Adapters with special features can be used with multiple lens mounts.  Such features include tilt, macro helicoid, and focal reducer.

Comment: Yea, I was trying to straddle the line between just telling OP that they're hosed and explaining why one could but probably doesn't exist. I like your take on this better.

Comment: @Hueco Thanks. I generally think likely duplicates and off-topic questions are fine to answer in the comments. Don't remember what prompted me to write this as an answer.